# recall and precision in lucene

Tags: java, lucene, precision-recall

I am a new lucene user. I am trying to calculate the recall/precision of
a query and I was wondering if lucene provides an easy way to do it.

Currently I have a number of documents that match a given query. Then I am
doing a search and I am getting back all the Hits. I then divide the number of
documents that came back from lucene (the Hits size) with the number of
documents that should have got. This is how I calculate the recall.

For precision I just get the hits.score() of each relevant document. I am not
sure if I am on the right track or if there is an easier/better way to do it. I
would appreciate any insigith into this.

Comment: I'm a few months late, but if you want to do something like that from lucene, there is a lot of stuff that is supposedly usable under https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/benchmark/index.html although the documentation is scarce and not that useful to me at least. Your best bet is something manual (either via code or via some other program that reads stuff you write in CSV files - i.e. Excel). Hope this helps and that I am not too late!

Comment: Thank you @chalarangelo ^^.